# Knapsack with items having multiple weights and price having constrained upper limit

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve the following problem and wondering if any variation of knapsack algorithm exists which is suitable to solve this

Problem:

> A thief enters a house with the intention of, well, stealing things. He needs x Kg of silver , y Kg of gold and z Kg of diamond. There are a number of items made of gold, silver and diamond in the house. Each item can contain these elements in any quantity (ie. it can be pure gold, or an alloy of gold and silver, or an alloy of gold and diamond and so on). Each of the items has a price tag attached to it.
>
> Now, our thief is one righteous man and he doesn't want the owner to hurt much, so he decides to steal the things such that the total cost of all the things in his bag is the **least possible**. The items kept there have multiple copies, so he **can keep the same item in his bag multiple times** . He won't mind if the quantity he keeps in the bag is a bit more than the requiremnt(X Kg, Y Kg, Z Kg) , given that the requirement could not be completed in a less costly way possible.

From what I have searched, I could not find any knapsack variant that deals with such a case. Please feel free to let me know if there exists some other way of solving this, that I am not looking at.

**EDIT**

One approach that I tried, was finding all possible combinations of the items satisfying the need and then iterating over them to find the least priced combination.However, this approach is quite ineffective once the combinations start getting larger

**EDIT 2**
I am adding an example for clarification;

Say, there are 5 items avaialble

> Material   |Gold | Silver| Diamond| Price
>
> Item1   |2   |3      |4       |2000
>
> Item2   |4   |3      |2       |1600
>
> Item3   |0    |3     |0       |200
>
> Item4   |20   |0     |10      |5000
>
> Item5   |15   |15    |0       |5500

The thief wanted 10 Kg of each gold , silver and diamond

He can choose (Item4 + Item5) or (3 X Item2 + Item1) to satisfy his need, but he'll choose the latter option as that has a price of 6800 compared to 10500 of the first.

Now, to get this result the thief thinks of each and every combinations of such items possible and then picks the combination having least price, but as I mentioned earlier it is not the best approach. Can this be somehow solved with any greedy algorithm?

Comment: What's stopping you from writing it yourself? You just need to adapt the classical knapsack algorithm.

Comment: The problem I have is that, there are multiple weights and thus multiple weight/price ratios. Hence, how would I decide which item is actually the least costliest.

Comment: `Each of the items has a price tag attached to it` and `less costly way possible` - sounds like you only need to worry about the price.

Comment: Usually it's also important to know whether the values for x, y, z and prices are integer or real. And the limits for input values. Then you should be able to decide whether dynamic programming approach is applicable here.

Comment: @algrid I have added an example scenario, maybe that helps.

Comment: No, you cannot solve the knapsack problem with a greedy algorithm.

Comment: @n.m. I do not necessarily need a solution using knapsack approach. Any way to get the optimal solution without taking into account all the possible solutions would do

Comment: The usual knapsack problem is *maximizing* quantity A while achieving *at most* some predetermined amount of quantity B. You have the variation of *minimising* quantity B while getting *at least* some predetermined amount of A. Usually A is presented as "price" and B is presented as "weight", but in your formulation it's the other way around. Doesn't matter one bit. Also, here B is a vector of 3 and you have to satisfy each dimension independently, which is also not unusual. All the usual algorithms should work.

Comment: Let's try again. You have a **knapsack type problem**. It is understandable that you want to solve it efficiently using any available method. Unfortunately no efficient solution exist in the general case as the problem is **NP-complete**. You may be able to use the dynamic programming approach if your input is made up of small integers.

Comment: @n.m. Here in the example we have multiple weights, thus giving multiple weight/price ratios for any given material. Now, I just can't seem to figure out how to move ahead in selecting the least priced Item. As far as I can understand, there is no chepest item here, it is all subjective related to which Material (Gold/Silver/Diamond) the thief wants more. Could you suggest something towards this.

Comment: Why are you trying to select the least priced Item? What algorithm are you trying to use?

Comment: Never mind, I was trying to get 1 item at a time, such that it covers most requirement and costs least. It doesn't work unfortunately. So , back to square one